# Can a gmail addon search/read other emails?

Tags: javascript, gmail-addons

Can a gmail addon search/read other emails?
I am trying to list matching emails in the addon.

```
function show_matching_emails(e) {
    var accessToken = e.messageMetadata.accessToken;
    GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken)

    var messageId = e.messageMetadata.messageId;
    var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
    var subject = message.getSubject();
    var sender = message.getFrom();

     var matches =  GmailApp.search(message.getSubject())
     var matching_emails="";
     for(var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
         var m = matches[i].getFirstMessageSubject()
         matching_emails= "matches" + m.getFirstMessageSubject()
     }

    var exampleCard = CardService.newCardBuilder()
        .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader()
            .setTitle('test email card'))
        .addSection(CardService.newCardSection()
            .addWidget(CardService.newKeyValue()
                .setTopLabel('Matching emails')
                .setContent(matching_emails)))
        .build();
    return [exampleCard];
}
```

I see the following

```
Access denied: : Missing access token for authorization. Request: MailboxService.GetThread. [line: 13, function: show_trigger, file: Code]
```

My authorization scopes are

```
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.storage",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
    "https://mail.google.com/"
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly in oauthScopes. You can learn more about the scopes [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/concepts/scopes#gmail_add-on_scopes).